# Interpolation using four nodes

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose there are four points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$ my target is to interpolate any point $x_I$ between $x_2$ and $x_3$.
Is there any Interpolation method which gives linear relation to find value of $y_I$ using above four point?
 I am looking for any numerical method or any approximation method (not Newton or Lagrange method)

Comment: Yes I would try Lagrange

Comment: Would you accept a cubic polynomial ? If yes, I could elaborate. Could you show your points ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, cubic polynomial is not required.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Actually i want to reduce multiplication part for reducing calculation time. If your method is faster or other than normal interpolating method (i.e n node point is given it can be approximately represented by a polynomial of n-1 degree), i will be glad to know.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sample points are (.81,.0117),(.90,.0186),(1.00,03058),(1.1,0.7861)

Comment: Consider asking at  [scicomp.se]